Which one is a better choice?

They grew up eating what their parents ate
They grew up eating what their parents eat

Which one is the correct one? And whats the difference between them?

The difference is the tense of the verb eat/ate.
The first uses past tense, so refers to what their parents ate at that time in the past.  The second uses the present tense, which is used for facts that are always true, in the present, past and future.
In most cases you probably are talking about what their parents ate when they were growing up and so would use the past tense.
